# Determine if one string occurs at the end of another

Tags: c, strings

> #### Exercise 5-4
>
> Write the function `strend(s,t)`, which returns one if the string `t` occurs at the end of the string `s`, and zero otherwise.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int str_end(const char *, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    char *s1 = "Man is a rope stretched over an abyss.";
    char *s2 = "an abyss.";

    printf("%s\n", str_end(s1, s2) ? "Yes" : "No");
    return 0;
}

int str_end(const char *s, const char *t)
{
    const char *init = t;       /* Hold the initial position of *t */

    while (*s) {
        while (*s == *t) { 
            if (!(*s)) {
                return 1;
            }
            s++;
            t++;
        }
        s++;
        t = init;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A few notes:

- Analyzing your code, I see a simple bug that isn't accounted for.  Consider the following case:

  ```
  char *s1 = "Man is a rope stretched over an abyss.";
  char *s2 = "an abyss..c9f0c50bc2e417b078e3b0bf82d5386d418cfba4";
  ```

  Your method still returns `1` even though it clearly shouldn't, because you only checked for `\0` in `*s` and not in `*t`.  You need to check if the `NULL` terminators are in matching positions.  Also, `s2` is clearly a larger string than `s1`, we never compared the lengths to see if `s2` could even fit into `s1`.
- You are somewhat approaching this inefficiently.  You are comparing all of the characters in the string.  You don't need to do this, we can just compare at the index `strlen(s) - strlen(t)`.
- You could shorten your while loop a bit.

  > ```
  >     while (*s == *t) { 
  >         if (!(*s)) {
  >             return 1;
  >         }
  >         s++;
  >         t++;
  >     }
  > ```

  Increment `*s` and `*t` inside of your `while` test conditional.
- You could also forgo the `while` loop completely and use the standard function [`strncmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/).  However, I would use [`memcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) since it is faster.
- You wouldn't need the function prototype if you define your `strend()` function before you define `main()`.
- <strike>What if you pass an invalid string to your function?  Right now it can't handle it and will throw a "Segmentation fault".  That's not any fun, so let's implement a simple test to check for that.</strike>

  ```
  if (!s || !t) return 0;
  ```

  Based on the discussion between @RolandIllig and myself, I have decided to **not** implement this check.  Why?  Because this is a runtime check that comes with a certain overhead time to process.  That time may not be much, but on certain systems (such as embedded ones) that processing power would be better used somewhere else.  Therefore, I decided to follow the philosophy behind the design of the C standard library: that the programmer is ultimately in the best position to know whether a runtime check really needs to be performed.
- I'm not sure how you want to handle empty strings.  I'm not going to mess with that too much since there was nothing stating so in the exercise.
- You should document all of your code.  Even for a simple function such as this.

---

## Final Product

```
#include <string.h>  // strlen(), memcmp()

/**
 * @fn int strend(const char *s, const char *t)
 * @brief Searches the end of string s for string t
 * @param s the string to be searched
 * @param t the substring to locate at the end of string s
 * @return one if the string t occurs at the end of the string s, and zero otherwise
 */
int strend(const char *s, const char *t)
{
    size_t ls = strlen(s); // find length of s
    size_t lt = strlen(t); // find length of t
    if (ls >= lt)  // check if t can fit in s
    {
        // point s to where t should start and compare the strings from there
        return (0 == memcmp(t, s + (ls - lt), lt));
    }
    return 0; // t was longer than s
}
```

---

## Tests and Benchmarking

Here are a few trial runs I did of the method, and their output.  All seems well by the tests.

- `strend("Man is a rope stretched over an abyss.", "an abyss..c9f0c");` returns `0`.
- `strend("Man is a rope stretched over an abyss.", "an abyss");` returns `0`.
- `strend("Man is a rope stretched over an abyss.", "an abyss.");` returns `1`.
- `strend("Man is an man man.", "an man.");` returns `1`.
- `strend("an abyssan abyssan abyssan abyss.", "an abyss.");` returns `1`.
- `strend(NULL, NULL);` returns `0`.

Using a benchmarking program I wrote to profile the code, I tested your function as well as the others supplied against mine.  Here are the results, averaged out over 100000000 test iterations:

> ```
> Search string: simple
> End string: le
> syb0rg's function average runtime: 1.47728e-08 seconds
> ao2130's function average runtime: 1.87163e-08 seconds
> Edward's function average runtime: 2.29287e-08 seconds
> Josay's function average runtime: 2.58304e-08 seconds
>
> Search string: this is a test
> End string: test
> syb0rg's function average runtime: 1.81173e-08 seconds
> ao2130's function average runtime: 4.7522e-08 seconds
> Edward's function average runtime: 2.31506e-08 seconds
> Josay's function average runtime: 4.62652e-08 seconds
>
> Search string: this is a longer string and may cause certain functions to take a bit longer to process
> End string: a bit longer to process
> syb0rg's function average runtime: 3.17312e-08 seconds
> ao2130's function average runtime: 2.44403e-07 seconds
> Edward's function average runtime: 3.33028e-08 seconds
> Josay's function average runtime: 3.25736e-07 seconds
> ```

As you can see, my function runs a tiny bit faster than yours and the other functions supplied here (watch the scientific notation).

Comment: This looks like a good solution to me (on my side I decided not to use `strlen` to be able to stop quickly is a string is order of magnitudes longer than the other) : you deserve my upvote. However, if you are to use the standard function, shouldn't you use `strcmp` to compare directly `t` and `s+ls-lt` ?

Comment: @Josay I agree, I should be more consistent.  The edit has been made (and the upvote already reciprocated `;)`).

Comment: re: silence compiler warning "Control may reach end of non-void function"
You reach this when the strings have incompatible length, so it's not the spurious warning that the comment implies.

Comment: @PierreMenard Correct, I'm not sure what I was thinking.  An edit has been made.

Comment: Suggest `size_t ls,lt` rather than `ssize_t ls,lt`.  See no reason for `ssize_t`.

Comment: This post has just been auto-flagged.  Please keep the edits to a minimum at this point.

Comment: @Jamal Sorry, I keep finding little tidbits to add and to fix.  I'll do my best.

Comment: The check for `!s || !t` should not be there. All the other `str*` functions don't have that check either.

Comment: @RolandIllig Those checks should be there. Without that check, if we submit a `NULL` `char*` we get a Segmentation fault.  We want to check for corner cases like that so that people using the function can rely on it in *all* circumstances.

Comment: So what if I call that function with `char s; strend("hello", &s + 17)`? Your code cannot check this. The `return 0` should better be an `abort()` in case of clearly illegal arguments.

Comment: @RolandIllig An `abort()` would be a very drastic measure to take, especially if we are talking about mimicking a standard library function.

Comment: @syb0rg: Well, the C standard library is even worse. Calling `strlen(NULL)` results in _undefined behavior_. Calling `abort()` is one step friendlier. Since a `string` is defined to be an `array of characters, terminated by a '\0' character`, all `str*` functions from the standard library assume that they never get called with `NULL`. Therefore it would only be natural for `strend` to follow that pattern.

Comment: @RolandIllig The philosophy behind the design of the C standard library is that the programmer is ultimately in the best position to know whether a runtime check really needs to be performed. Back in the days when your total system memory was measured in kilobytes, the overhead of performing an unnecessary runtime check could be pretty painful. So the C standard library doesn't bother doing any of those checks. But now we have the hardware to do the heavy-lifting for us.  So instead of making the programmer perform that check outside of the function, I moved it inside.

Comment: @RolandIllig Now that I look back on it, I think you are right.  I should give the programmer the choice of using runtime checks rather than forcing them to perform them; especially if they plan to use the function on an embedded system with constrained resources. An edit will be made.

Comment: @syb0rg does your code-editor automatically populate those comments with snippets, or how do you usually add your documentation? What code editor is it from? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

A simpler way to do this would be to start from the end instead of the beginning.

```
int str_end(const char *s, const char *t)
{
    if (strlen(s) < strlen(t)) return 0;
    return 0 == strcmp(&s[strlen(s)-strlen(t)], t);
}
```

To avoid calling `strlen` more than needed, this code is slightly faster:

```
int str_end(const char *s, const char *t)
{
    int diff = strlen(s)-strlen(t);
    return diff > 0 && 0 == strcmp(&s[diff], t);
}
```

Comment: I would store the string length values so you don't have to recalculate them.  Otherwise, you have earned my +1!

Comment: I don't think it matters how you store the lengths; you still have to `strlen()` both strings, which is dramatically more expensive than storing an integer in memory.

Comment: Note: The difference of `strlen(s)-strlen(t)` may not fit in an `int`.

Comment: I read that you should cast out of size_t when using values from strlen() etc, as it can have side effects. Is this what you are talking about chux?

Comment: @ao2130: The issue is signed versus unsigned.  `size_t` is an unsigned quantity but `int` is obviously signed.  Also [discussed in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202241/what-type-for-subtracting-2-size-ts)

Comment: `strlen()` is fast. Probably faster than scanning the string yourself, even with an optimal state machine. And of course you'd have to construct the state machine too.

Comment: @Snowbody: yes, it's fast.  In fact with that small optimization included it's faster than all of the other answers in my testing.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately your code has a bug. If there is a mis-match on the end-string, you roll-back the pointer for the end-string to the `init` value. You should also roll-back the pointer in the `s` string so that you can look for cases where the actual result starts part-way through the failed match.

This is easier to describe with an example. Consider the nonsense input values:

> ```
> Man is an man man
> ```

with the search phrase:

> ```
> an man
> ```

The text does end with `an man`, but your code will say it does not. [Here is an ideone showing this problem](http://ideone.com/r226Sw).

You need to back-track your text pointer as well as the search pointer.

And, in other news, the variable names `s` and `t` are not very descriptive, and makes it hard to simply read your code. Consider names like `text` and `search`, or something that actually describes what the variables are.....

Answer (score 5):

I was about to say that I had found a bug with the following test cases while trying to understand how your logic works :

```
char *s1 = "an abyssan abyssan abyssan abyss.";
char *s2 = "an abyss.";

char *s1 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.";
char *s2 = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.";
```

I reckon you should start by writing test cases and check that your code produces the results you are expecting.

For instance, here is what I have written. I won't say it's bug free because I haven't spent much time on it but at least I have a bit of confidence because it seems to go through the different tests I have written :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int str_end(const char *s, const char *t)
{
    // Going forward on both strings til we reach an end
    int l;
    for (l=0; *s && *t; s++, t++, l++);

    // If t is not over ... 
    if (*t)
    {
        // ... then s should be
        assert(!*s);
        // so s is shorter and there is no point in going further
        return 0;
    }

    assert(!*t);

    // Going forward on s
    for ( ; *s; s++);

    // Going backward on both -- this could also be done with a normal string comparison function by going back l steps and comparing remaining strings
    for ( ; l>=0; l--, s--, t--)
        if (*s != *t)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    assert( str_end("Man is a rope stretched over an abyss.", "an abyss."));
    assert(!str_end("Man is a rope stretched over an abyss.", "un abyss."));
    assert( str_end("Man is a rope stretched over an abyss.", ""));
    assert( str_end("", ""));
    assert( str_end(".", "."));
    assert( str_end(".", ""));
    assert(!str_end("", "."));
    assert( str_end("qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq", "qq"));
    return 0;
}
```